# Android call another app with option onstop

Tags: android, android-intent

First of all i am sorry of my language:)
I have Application to showing available pdf files, which is downloading from server. Next I want to call available Application to show Pdf. When App to show Pdf is closed, i want to delete file from external storage.
Code of call another App:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    java.util.List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no way to reliably know "when App to show Pdf is closed", so you cannot delete the file this way.

You are welcome to give the user an option within your app to delete the file when the user knows that it is no longer needed.